# New to CSS/div... stuck adding ad block

Tags: css, layout, html

After years editing my site in very basic HTML (no CSS) I've decided it's time to join the real world & attempt some proper code.  I'm just managing to get my head around CSS by I've realised that laying my site out using tables, as I have in the past, isn't the best way around it.  Problem is I've hit a brick wall trying to get my head around the div tags.

What I am trying to replicate are the ad blocks as with this old-style page: http://pageantupdate.info/missusa2012/statepageantcalendar.htm

At the moment I'm stuck with this situation: 
http://pageantupdate.info/missusa2013/statepageantcalendar.htm

What I need to figure out is how to float/move the horizontal ad box so it sits flush with the main text area, at the top right.  I've attempted to move the code above that for the header box etc but the float:right moves it all the way to the right of the page, not just the box.

I'm guessing the issue is that I'm still using tables for the other stuff!

Any help with fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Both hyperlinks you provided are the same page. I wouldn't recommend replacing certain bits of the mark up with css and not the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I've corrected the second link.  Yeah, I'm almost at the point of giving up and going back to what I know, I think I'm biting off more than I can chew and some weird combo of css/not css isn't going to work.

Comment: Do you want an exact replica of your site? I'll create it quick for you as an introduction if you like

Comment: I'd really appreciate it!  I have hundreds of pages for each "year" section (just attempting to use CSS to set up the new 2013 section) and having correct coding to start off with would be incredibly helpful... I figure if I can start with one page I should be able to figure out the rest.  I assume you can just access the source for each & figure out what's gone wrong?

Comment: Ok, this is very quickly done, so its pretty sloppy.

My version: http://www.afishwick.com/stackOverflow/test.html

To view my html, right click and view source.
To view my css, click the css link in the html source (looks somethnig like <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" title="main" type="text/css" />.

Added some comments in to explain certain bits, give me a shout if you don't understand something

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have a play with it and get back to you if I get stuck.  I'm very grateful!